# Can't read pdf file on ios (react native)

Tags: react-native, pdf

I'm using `react-native-pdf` for displaying pdf which is stored in `/var/lib/.../file.pdf`.

But it returns error "Load file failed".

It works on android though.

```
<Pdf
  source={{ uri: source }}
  scale={1}
  horizontal={false}
  onError={(error) => {
    console.log('pdf error', error)
  }}
  style={styles.pdf}
/>
```

RN version: 0.60 
react-native-pdf: 6.0.0
rn-fetch-blob: 0.11.2

Can someone help please? Thanks

Comment: For iOS, I had to do the following, you need to include `file.pdf `into your Xcode project and make sure it's added to your build target. What is in your `source` variable?

Comment: I'm using Scanbot in my app which generates pdf file from scanned documents and stores it to default device location.
I was able to fix this by adding custom storage path for pdf. 
Pdf is loaded successfully now.

Comment: @arminn why you don't add your solution ? i need it :(

Comment: Are there any more tips on how this one was solved?  We're running into a similar issue.